# Google sign-in issue in implementing the one-time-code flow

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, google-signin

I have a dot net core Web API project which makes use of Google Login using oAuth 2.0.
Have followed the same code as per : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow

code snippet:

```
var requestUrl = $"oauth2/v4/token?code={code.code}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={SecretKey}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&grant_type=authorization_code";

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
};

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
var httpResponse = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GmailToken>(await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
var obj = await GetuserProfile(token.AccessToken);
```

Response:
Http status 400

```
{
  "error": "redirect_uri_mismatch",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have correct URL on developer console and one that has been passed in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You will receive this error message when the configured Redirect URL under https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials > "OAuth 2.0 client IDs" does not **exactly** match the value of your `{RedirectUrl}` parameter.
This includes trailing `/`